# Blazor Server Method not getting Hit from Blazor Client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have the following method in the Blazor Server

```
public partial class UploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("upload/blah")]
    public void blah()
    {

    }
}
```

But when trying to call this endpoint from the client side (Blazor client)

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Navigator.BaseUri+ "/upload/blah");

var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();

var response = await client.GetAsync(Navigator.BaseUri + "/upload/blah");

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();        
}
else { }
```

The endpoint is never being hit in the debugger , but in the browser console window I get

[image: https://localhost:5001]

Comment: I have a similar issue. Request URL is correct (no // issue) but same behavior. Funny thing is that if I change the request to say "ubload/myblah" and the route of the controller to the same, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You have // in your Request URL.
Try

```
Navigator.BaseUri+ "upload/blah");
```

Other than that, check if `ClientFactory.CreateClient();` has a preset URL.

Also a simple trick to make sure you hit a breakpoint is: do a `await Task.Delay(10000);` on app startup to ensure that the debugger has had enough time to hook into the app.